# How do I create a dictionary where I add points to names form a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, addition

I am trying to make sort of a scoring system, I got a textfile with a huge ammount of (players). I have created a dictionary and managed to add all the names in it, but when I am trying to add the points they only get the last number, not all of them combined for each name. So how do I create a new dictionary for each name and then add the points corresponding to the name?

So I basicly need to take one of the names "Anders Johansson" and add his score to his name in the dictionary, his name will exist in the score.txt multiple times with different score.

My thought is that I need ot run down the entire score file and create one instance of every name, then add the corresponding score to each name, "Anders Johansson" may appear up to 100 times in the score.txt.
this code will get the names in to final_score but not the total score.

```
final_list, file, final_score = [], open('score.txt','r'), {}
string = file.read()
lista = string.split('\n') 
lista.sort()
for i in lista[1:]:
    final_score[str(i[0:-2])] = 0
    final_score[str(i[0:-2])] += int(i[-2:]) # possible error location
final_list = list(final_score.items())
print(sorted(final_list, key=lambda score: score[1],reverse=True))

Example from the file:
Anders Johansson 1
Karin Johansson 1
Eva Johansson 0
Erik Andersson 1
Gunnar Andersson 2
Eva Andersson 1
Nils Eriksson 1
Anders Eriksson 0
Maria Eriksson 1
and so on:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

final_score = defaultdict(int)

for i in lista[1:]:
    final_score[str(i[0:-2])] += int(i[-2:]) #
```

In your code you keep **resetting** the value to `0` with `final_score[str(i[0:-2])] = 0` every time you find the **name/key** so that is why you only actually add the last score each time.

You would need to check if the key existed or not and proceed based on the outcome of that or a simpler approach would be to use a [dict.setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) in your own code which creates a `key/value` pairing if the key does not exist or else does nothing:

```
for i in lista[1:]:
    final_score.setdefault(str(i[0:-2]), 0)
    final_score[str(i[0:-2])] += int(i[-2:]) # possible error location
```

You are also doing more work than needed, there is no need to sort, we can iterate over the file object and use `rsplit` to get the `name` and `score`:

```
final_score =  defaultdict(int)

with open('score.txt','r') as f: # with will automatically close your file
    for line in f: # iterate over file object
        # split once on whitespace from right side of string, separating name from score 
        name, score = line.rsplit(None,1)  # unpack 
        # use our defaultdict to increment the score
        final_score[name] += int(score) 

# just call sorted on .items()
print(sorted(final_score.items(), key=lambda score: score[1], reverse=True))
```

There is no need to sort as whenever we come across a name we update the value in the dict, it does not matter what order we come across the names, that is indeed one of advantages of using a dict.

Also for sorting `final_list.items()` using [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) will be more efficient than using a lambda:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(final_list.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
```

Comment: Thank you, I am stil new to python so I come across good and to me unknown functions all the time.

Comment: @FredrikCarlsson, no worries. There a a few  really nice tools in the `collections` library worth checking out.